# LD+JSON Use for SameAs Product

Tags: linked-data, json

Assume you have an eCommerce site from which you sell some product.  You also sell that product on Amazon.  What would be the SEO implications of using the `sameAs` property in your eCommerce site's ld+json to link to your Amazon URL as well?  Is this a valid practice and would you gain anything by it?

For example:

```
{
   "@context":"https://schema.org/",
   "@type":"Product",
   "sameAs":[AMAZON URL HERE],
   "name":"My Product",
   "image":"myproductimage.jpg",
   "description":"my description",
   "brand":{
      "@type":"Thing",
      "name":"Brand"
   },
   "sku":"SKU",
   "mpn":"MPN",
   "offers":{ ... }
}
```